# find the time different between records with multiple starttimes but same stoptime

Tags: sql-server

this is my table.

```
id  section  secstart                   secstop
101 1       2010-03-06 02:27:49.000       2010-03-06 02:34:32.000
101 2       2010-03-06 02:28:25.000       2010-03-06 02:34:32.000
101 3       2010-03-06 02:29:58.000       2010-03-06 02:34:32.000
102 1       2008-09-11 02:15:22.000       2008-09-11 02:34:55.000
102 2       2008-09-11 02:25:32.000       2008-09-11 02:34:55.000
```

for an id, I want to find out time taken for each section.
 As you can see that the secstart time for each section is different but the secstop time is same for all the sections for an id. so the time taken for section 1 would be secstart(2) - sectstart(1) and so on but for the last section the time would be secstop - secstart.
 I want the results to look like following:

```
id  section         secstart    secstop diff
101 1   3-6-2010 2:27:49    3-6-2010 2:34:32    1
101 2   3-6-2010 2:28:25    3-6-2010 2:34:32    1
101 3   3-6-2010 2:29:58    3-6-2010 2:34:32    5
102 1   9-11-2008 2:15:22   9-11-2008 2:34:55   10
102 2   9-11-2008 2:25:32   9-11-2008 2:34:55   9
```

Comment: What is the datatype for secstart and secstop?

Comment: its a timestamp

Comment: Do you mean datetime? Those are not valid values for a datetime. The timestamp datatype is something entirely different and has nothing to do with the time of day.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATEDIFF()`:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(Second, secstart, secstop)
  FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the `min()` start time, and the `max()` end time for each `ID`--then use `DATEDIFF()`.

```
with cte as(
select
    ID
    ,min(secstart) as secstart
    ,max(secstop) as secstop
from
    YourTable
group by ID)

select
    ID
    ,datediff(minute,secstart,secstop)
from
    cte
```

**EDIT**

```
declare @table table (id int, section int, secstart datetime, secstop datetime)
insert into @table
values
(101,1,'2010-03-06 02:27:49.000','2010-03-06 02:34:32.000'),
(101,2,'2010-03-06 02:28:25.000','2010-03-06 02:34:32.000'),
(101,3,'2010-03-06 02:29:58.000','2010-03-06 02:34:32.000'),
(102,1,'2008-09-11 02:15:22.000','2008-09-11 02:34:55.000'),
(102,2,'2008-09-11 02:25:32.000','2008-09-11 02:34:55.000')


select
    id
    ,section
    ,DATEDIFF(minute,secstart,secstop) MinuteDifference
from @table

select
    x.id
    ,x.section
    ,DATEDIFF(minute,x.secstart,t.secstart) MinuteDifference
from 
    @table x
left join 
    @table t on 
    t.section = x.section + 1 
    and t.id = x.id
```

Comment: this does not give me the correct section time for each section. If you notice each section have different start time but all the sections have same stop time which is the end of the call. for example if there are 3 sections, section 1 duration would be (section 2 secstart - section 1 secstart), similarly for section 2 duration it would be (section3 secstart - section2 secstart) and for section 3 it would be (secstop - section 3 secstart) ,Your answer doesn't give me the correct output. I'm not sure if I need to write a stored procedure for this. thanks!

Comment: see my edit @user8395616. All you need is a simple DATEDIFF function. I showed you how the result would be the same by finding the last secstop as well

Comment: this only give me the time diff for each segment from the start time of each section to the actual stop time. your results give me this:

Comment: Can you post what the results should be?

Comment: this only give me the time diff for each segment from the start time of each section to the actual stop time. please look at the following results and it will show your results and actual desired results                                                                                                         id  section   MinuteDifference  Actual desired diff
101     1     7                       1
101     2     6                       1
101    3    5                       5
102     1    19                     10
102    2           9                     9

Comment: MinuteDifference
1
1
5
10
9

Comment: can you post that in the original question so i can see what value goes with what row?

Comment: that's because there is no row above the last row, of course